# How to remove all Google-specific apps from a rooted Android?

Tags: applications, root-access, apk, google

Some time ago I read somewhere that Chinese carriers are removing Google-specific software (Google Search, Google Play, etc) from Android devices they carry.

What I wanted to know is if this is difficult to do on already rooted Android tablets?

I know that I can log into a rooted Android tablet through a USB cable and delete packages, I am just not sure which ones can be deleted without causing dependency issues.

Is it sufficient to delete Velvet.apk, or do other ones need to be deleted to remove all out-of-the box Google apps?

Comment: If your on a custom ROM you can reflash it without the GApps package....no Google Apps!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install an app like [**Root Uninstaller**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.free) or [**Link2SD**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) and remove any unwanted system apps from there. It is typically safe to remove:

- Cloud Print
- Drive
- Google Photos
- Google Play Books
- Google Play Games
- Google Play Magazines
- Google Play Movies & TV
- Google Play Music
- Google Play Store
- Google Photos
- Google Search
- Google Text-to-speech Engine
- Google+
- Google Text-to-speech Engine
- Hangouts/Talk
- Translate
- YouTube

Be careful, removing these may break some functionality:

- Gmail (reinstalling as user app may break functionality)
- Google Backup Transport
- Google Calendar Sync
- Google Contacts Sync
- Google Maps
- Google Now Launcher (do only if there's an alternate launcher installed as system app)
- Google One Time Init
- Street View

Do not remove these:

- Google Account Manager (causes FC's if you don't remove other gapps)
- Google Partner Setup (**may** cause unexplained crashes)
- Google Play Services (causes FC's if you don't remove other related gapps)
- Google Services Framework (may cause crashes if you don't remove other gapps)
- Setup Wizard

## You may want to disable these apps first (**Settings > Apps > All > [Selected system app] > Disable**) *or* [Freeze using Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) to test functionality with those apps removed.

---

Thanks to [user1261104's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91628/how-to-remove-all-google-specific-apps-from-a-rooted-android/91641?noredirect=1#comment115241_91641) for contribution to this answer.

Comment: Also safe to remove: Gmail,Google+,Google (the search app),Google Play (the market),Youtube and I think SIM toolkit as well. Just disable these apps via Settings>Apps>All apps> [Choose an app] >Disable. If you find that everything still works like you'd expect, delete them with Titanium Backup or Root Uninstaller like LyricWulf says.

Comment: Lollipop won't allow you to disable Play services / Google Now

Comment: @HelloWorld That may be true, but with root access, disabling and removing GApps is possible. As OP stated, the target device is rooted.